# Substitution of factors of the free term to find factors of a cubic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring, cubics

I was taught that finding a factor (and hence a solution) of a cubic equation may be easier if I try if the factors of the free term are roots of the equation. For example, if one has an equation $x^3-4x^2+9x-10=0$, then they should try substituting the factors of 10 (1, 2, 5, 10) and see if it makes the polynomial equal to zero. If it does, then (x - this factor) will be a factor of the polynomial. Then the remaining factor (quadratic in the case of a cubic equation) can be easily found by trial and error or by long division.
My questions are:

1) Why does substituting factors of the free term work? What's the intuition and/or proof behind this?

2) What are the limitations of this method? Will it always work, if no, what are the limitations/assumptions?

3) Will this method work for higher order polynomials too (for example quartic)?

Answer (score 1):

1. This method is known as the [Rational Roots Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem?wprov=sfla1), and more specifically one can test all factors of the form $\frac{s}{t}$, where $s$ is a divisor of the free term (the constant) and $t$ is a divisor of the coefficient of the highest powered term.
2. This method only gives rational roots, so it does not work for a polynomial such as $x^2-2=0$, which has irrational roots.
3. Yes, this method extends to any polynomial.